# Why not use min_score with Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

New to Elasticsearch. I am interested in only returning the most relevant docs and came across [min_score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-min-score.html). They say "Note, most times, this does not make much sense" but doesn't provide a reason. So, why does it not make sense to use min_score?

EDIT: What I really want to do is only return documents that have a higher than x "score". I have this:

```
data = {
        'min_score': 0.9,
        'query': {
            'match': {'field': 'michael brown'},
        }
    }
```

Is there a better alternative to the above so that it only returns the most relevant docs?

thx!

EDIT #2:
I'm using minimum_should_match and it returns a 400 error:

```
"error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed;"

data = {
        'query': {
            'match': {'keywords': 'michael brown'},
            'minimum_should_match': '90%',
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not very useful unless you are calculating scores yourself for results, and even then they would likely need to be fully controller by you. I've never used min_score despite using scoring boosts because I never cared for minimum score vs minimum should match. I only use score for sorting and top n searching

Comment: I've also tried using minimum_should_match but it returns a "400" status. I've updated my question.

Comment: how were you using minimum_should_match? the thing about min_score is what does 0.9 mean? how have you defined what is 'good enough' based on the score (unless you are generating that scoring using a boost/function)

Comment: I randomly just picked .9. I'm sure I'll have to test it more with my data and maybe something like .3 rather than .9. I'll update my question w/ how I was using minimum_should_match

Comment: You can only use a minimum_should_match in a bool query. Nothing else has any shoulds to match.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've used min_score quite a lot for trying to find documents that are a definitive match to a given set of input data - which is used to generate the query.

The score you get for a document depends on the query, of course. So I'd say try your query in many permutations (different keywords, for example) and decide which document is the first you would rather it didn't return for each, and and make a note of each of their scores. If the scores are similar, this would give you a good guess at the value to use for your min score.

However, you need to bear in mind that score isn't just dependant on the query and the returned document, it considers all the other documents that have data for the fields you are querying. This means that if you test your min_score value with an index of 20 documents, this score will probably change greatly when you try it on a production index with, for example, a few thousands of documents or more. This change could go either way, and is not easily predictable.

I've found for my matching uses of min_score, you need to create quite a complicated query, and set of analysers to tune the scores for various components of your query. But what is and isn't included is vital to my application, so you may well be happy with what it gives you when keeping things simple.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if it's the best solution, but it works for me (java):

```
// "tiny" search to discover maxScore
// it is fast, because it returns only 1 item
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(INDEX_NAME)
                        .setTypes(TYPE_NAME)
                        .setQuery(queryBuilder)
                        .setSize(1)
                        .execute()
                        .actionGet();

// get the maxScore and
// and set minScore = 70%
float maxScore = response.getHits().maxScore();
float minScore = maxScore * 0.7;

// second round with minimum score
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(INDEX_NAME)
                        .setTypes(TYPE_NAME)
                        .setQuery(queryBuilder)
                        .setMinScore(minScore)
                        .execute()
                        .actionGet();
```

I search twice, but the first time it's fast because it returns only 1 item, then we can get the max_score

NOTE: minimum_should_match work different. If you have 4 queries, and you say minimum_should_match = 70%, it doesn't mean that item.score should be > 70%. It means that the item should match 70% of the queries, that is minimum 3/4 queries

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Sorry for commenting on a 4-year old thread, but just thought I'd put this here for anyone else who uses this approach. If you're feeling sceptical about making 2 queries, you can just do the query without the minScore and your normal size, and then manually filter out any post that has a score < minScore.

Comment: I would not recommend to filter out in java:
If your query find a lot of documents, then you lose performance when ES returns your data and you will not need all of them (if you say min_score = 70% it means you will filter out 70% of your data). The "two-rounds" approach is faster because of less data to transform.

The first request is fast because ES stop searching when the maxSize is reached and if you retrieve only one field, then it is even faster.

Comment: If your query finds, lets say 50 documents, then the "two-rounds" approach is slower, but we are talking about < 10 ms, but if you find more than 10 MB and you need only a couple of hundreds, then two-rounds is really faster.